# Add fade effect to a jquery function

Tags: jquery

I like too add a fade effect to a jquery function.
The following code changing a divs background image with jquery,

Thanks for any help :)

```
  $(function () {
      var circle = $("#verschluss");

      $(".verschluss").selectmenu({
          change: function (event, data) {
              circle.css("background-image", data.item.value);
          }
      });



  });
```

html:

```
  <div id="verschluss"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()` or `fadeToggle()`

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn